# How to match a delimiter if present, or end of string if not, and extract it using a regex expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm parsing some fields out of a string, and I'm having a bit of difficulty getting the extraction correct.

My string can be formatted as such:

```js
const myString = 'field1=field1_value;field2=field2_value'
```

Or

```js
const myString = 'field1=field1_value'
```

In this example below, I'm trying to extract field1 and field2 out of the first string.

I've done something like:

```js
const field1 = myString.match(/field1=(.*)(;)?/);
const field2 = myString.match(/field2=(.*)(;)?/);
```

The problem with this, is that for field1, it will match all the way from the beginning until the end of the string, including all the other fields. If I make the delimiter a mandatory match, then field2 doesn't match anything, as the last field in the string won't have any delimiters. I want this extraction to happen in a way that if a delimiter is present, it should only match up to that and since the last field doesn't have it, or if it is a single field without the delimiter, it should still extract it.

How can I form my regex to do this type of extraction?

Comment: Use: `.match(/\bfield1=([^;]+)/)`

Answer (score 1):

For a simple pattern like this you don't actually need regex. You could just do something like this: `myString.split(';').map(field => field.split('=')[1])` to get an array of values.

Answer (score 0):

Your first group should be non-greedy, matching as few characters as possible before the next group. The same would work for subsequent fields as long as they end with a semicolon.

```
const field1 = myString.match(/field1=(.*?)(;)/);
const field2 = myString.match(/field2=(.*)/);
```

However, if your final field doesn't end in a semicolon, you'd need a different regex for it.

**Edit:** Disregard this answer.  Anubjava gave you a much better solution in the comments:

```
const field1 = myString.match(/\bfield1=([^;]+)/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
(\w+)=([^;]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/DNkHIR/1).